# Subset R table dimensions by name

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, subset

I have a 3D `table()` output. How do I subset a 2D table by name?

```
dim1 <- LETTERS
dim2 <- letters
dim3 <- 1:26
tbl <- table(dim1, dim2, dim3)
names(attr(tbl, "dimnames")) # dim1, dim2 dim3

table(dim1, dim2) # how do I get this output without redoing the tabulation?
```

Comment: What do you mean "by calling 'dim1' and 'dim2'"? Your array subset is equivalent to `tbl["A", , ]`. In this context, `dim1` refers to the whole dimension, not a specific slice.

Comment: You’re right, the question isn’t posed correctly. I want to subset the equivalent of `table(dim1, dim2)`. This is part of a function so won’t always know the indices, just the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `margin.table` or `marginSums`. The two functions are the same. The second is more descriptive, but the first was the original name. To collapse the 3 dimensional array to 2 dimensions:

```
margin.table(tbl, c("dim1", "dim2"))   # Or margin.table(tbl, 1:2)
```

will give you the same as

```
table(dim1, dim2)
```